# Why is an aluminum track not performing as a voltage divider?

Tags: voltage-divider

I have an arm that moves along a track. I need to know its location. My idea was to have a wiper on the arm that acts as the output of a voltage divider. The voltage could then be sent to the microcontroller and be converted into the location.

Just to test things out, I attached two ends of a piece of aluminum foil to a battery. My idea was that the aluminum foil has some relatively consistent resistance across it, thus the center should provide half the voltage.

I could not get a reading on my multimeter. I then coiled nichrome wire around a rod and used the same divider method as above and it worked. Why is this?

Comment: What's the resistivity of your aluminum foil (take a guess)? Compare that to the resistivity of your nichrome wire. I think that should give you a good idea.

Comment: After you've guessed take a resistance measurement of the foil and the nichrome. After that measure the battery voltage when you connect the foil and compare it with when you connect the nichrome.

Comment: The aluminium track will act as a voltage divider, though with such low resistance you'll have difficulty measuring the voltage accurately enough. However, the oxide layer on the aluminium makes it quite unlikely that your wiper will make good contact. (Especially if the aluminium component is anodised, but it's still going to be a problem with foil).

Comment: So put the Nichrome wire on top of a piece of fish paper or other insulator and use that. The aluminum is way too low resistance to get enough voltage across it without a massive current.

Comment: Just for fun, try measuring the battery voltage with the aluminum track connected.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast but you should warn him not to use a car battery.

Comment: Your scenario of a bar of aluminum (a large, low resistance conductor) is similar to the scenario of a railroad locomotive moving down a track towards a grade crossing with a signal or gate: a large, low resistance conductor of varying resistance. There is in fact an analog device which is capable of measuring such a low resistance in a time-varying way (it takes in to account the first derivative - how fast the train is moving) to decide when to turn on the signal or gate. You could look in to how this circuit performs that function, as I am sure you will learn much about your situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aluminum readily developes a non-conductive coating (oxide?) when exposed to air, so you may not have actually made contact with the actual conductive aluminum.

Aluminum is a very good conductor (if you can get through the oxide) so will not develope a significant voltage - it will just be a short circuit on the battery.

Nichrome is a fairly high resistance material, and a length of wire coiled around a rod will have a much higher resistance than a sheet of aluminum foil, so you can easily measure the voltage developed across part of the coil.

Comment: Perhaps this is why they used nichrome for early "rheostats". I always wondered why they didn't use bars of aluminum : ) Bars of silver are right out, despite the oxide being very conductive.